# Stuck on Nonogram 15x15

Tags: nonogram

I have recently started solving Nonograms, and i really love it. But there is this 15x15 Nonogram that I am not able to proceed with. Could anyone please help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the second last column

> If the square in the second row is shaded then there is no place to put the last "1" in the second row. Hence, the cell in the second row cannot be shaded. You should be able to make a lot of progress from here (For example, this means the top cell in that column must be shaded).
>  Diagram for illustration [image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try to solve it from here..

Comment: Can confirm. That deduction is the lynch-pin to transitioning to the left side.

Answer (score 1):

> The second-to-last cell of the second row has to be empty (filling it would leave no room for the 1). From there, we know that the first 1 of the 1 1 2 5 column needs to be in the first cell (only way to fit in two 1's). From there, we already know most of the first row.